# Rails 5.1 mailer encoding errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, email-validation

I'm following the Hartl Rails tutorial, v5.0.1 and got stuck on a Mailer test that (presumably) expects a specified encoding.

The relevant test clauses (I get similar errors on either line):

```
assert_match user.reset_token, mail.body.encoded
assert_match CGI.escape(user.email), mail.body.encoded
```

The resulting error msg (truncated):

```
Failure:    
UserMailerTest#test_password_reset    
[...demo/test/mailers/user_mailer_test.rb:30]:    
Expected /6qyclXtvAeFin0htTK7t7g/ to match # encoding: US-ASCII
```

Please note that I'm using Rails 5.1.1 in my local repo. The mailer templates are using the default encodings, whatever they may be.

The error msg includes a long string of the email template; I can see "charset=UTF-8" and "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".

The MailerTest file also checks the same combination of user token and CGI-escaped email address for an account activation test case w/o issue.

Any suggestions? The Hartl tutorial hasn't delved into encodings up to this point.

Comment: Please share the mailer file you are testing (i assume it is `user_mailer.rb`)  and its templates (e.g. `some_mail.html.erb` and `some_mail.txt.erb`).

Comment: https://pastebin.com/67GS6Rwg

Comment: Its better to edit your question and add the code there rather than providing an external link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `mail.body` must be a `String`, but you haven't set it yet in `password_reset`.

So, first set it:

```
def password_reset(user)
  @user = user
  @body = "My message body"

  mail to: user.email, subject: "password reset"
end
```

And, second, use it in your template.

```
# password_reset.html.erb
<h1>User#password_reset</h1>
<%= @body %>

# password_reset.text.erb
User#password_reset
<%= @body %>
```

You will notice that `@greeting` has been removed, i did so because it is not longer being used (you will add your message in `@body`).